# How to split words up in a cell by a comma in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

i have the following dataframe,

```
id food drink 
1  chip coke, wine, punch
2  eggs pepsi, water
3  pie  water, wine, orange juice
```

I want to know how i can get the following dataframe instead:

```
id food drink 
1  chip coke 
1  chip wine 
1  chip punch 
2  eggs pepsi 
2  eggs water 
3  pie  water 
3  pie  wine 
3  pie  orange juice
```

i would like to use something from the tidyverse such as the stringr pacakge - but am stuck at the moment

any ideas how to do this in R?

Comment: Too complex for beginners - my question easier to understand

Comment: There are 4 answers posted there, 2 of which give several options with several packages. One of those answers is the same as the one you've accepted. Are they all too complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(df1, drink, sep=", ")
#   id food  drink
#1  1 chip   coke
#2  1 chip   wine
#3  1 chip  punch
#4  2 eggs  pepsi
#5  2 eggs  water
#6  3  pie  water
#7  3  pie   wine
#8  3  pie orange juice
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, food = c("chip", "eggs", "pie"),
 drink = c("coke, wine, punch", 
 "pepsi, water", "water, wine, orange juice")), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

another way you can solve this problem is with tidytext

```
library(tidytext)
unnest_tokens(df, drink)
```

This wil split that text column up into words.
You can also use it for other unnesting but this works. 
See more info here: https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html#the-unnest_tokens-function